# Feature Selection Accuracy of 1.0?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection

I have a data set and am trying to select the number of predictive features to output when running it through the RFE. I used predictive mean imputation to fill in missing variables first and then tried estimating number of features for selection. When I try anywhere from 5-15 features, they all give me an accuracy of 1.0 with a std of 0.0. This doesn't make sense to me because the data set is patient data and I would not expect it to have an accuracy of 1.0 since it is randomized. I included my code below...can someone help me understand why this may be and whether my code/datatset structure may be faulty?

Last time I had this problem it was due to data leakage but I can't find the reason this time even it is the same problem.

One thought I had was the way I split my data between x and y may not be appropriate. The y = imp_data.iloc[:,37] is a binary variable that is either 0.0 or 1.0 which may mean that the majority of variables will be predictive of variable y.

A second idea I had was that I do have some missing data that I chose not to remove for the sake of the exercise...I was thinking maybe doing it at the end once I have the predictive models completed. The mean data missing is 10.9% and the median data missing is 3.8%. Maybe this is playing with the feature selection accuracy?

Enough of my blabber...here's the input and outputs:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX.xlsx')
missing_values = ['NA', 'n/a', '-', ' ', 'N/A', #N/A']
data = pd.read_excel('/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX.xlsx')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
imp_mean = IterativeImputer(estimator = RandomForestRegressor(), random_state=0)
imp_mean.fit(data)
imp_data = pd.DataFrame(imp_mean.transform(data))
imp_data.columns = [ALL MY VARIABLES]
from sklearn import datasets
x = imp_data.iloc[:, :35]
y = imp_data.iloc[:,37]
from numpy import mean, std
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from matplotlib import pyplot
def get_models():
   models = dict()
   for i in range(4,16):
      rfe = RFE(estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(), n_features_to_select = i)
      model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
      models[str(i)] = Pipeline(steps = [('s', rfe), ('m', model)])
return models
get_models()
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
def evaluate_model(model, x ,y):
   cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 3, random_state = 1)
   scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = cv, n_jobs=-1,error_score = 'raise')
   return scores
evaluate_model(model, x, y)
models = get_models()
results, names = list(), list()
for name, model in models.items():
   scores = evaluate_model(model, x, y)
   results.append(scores)
   print('>%s %.3f (%.3f)' % (name, mean(scores), std(scores)))

> array([1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ,
   1.   , 1.   , 0.875, 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ,
   1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ,
   1.   , 1.   , 1.   ])
>4 0.996 (0.022)
>5 0.996 (0.022)
>6 0.996 (0.022)
>7 0.996 (0.022)
>8 0.996 (0.022)
>9 0.996 (0.022)
>10 0.996 (0.022)
>11 0.996 (0.022)
>12 0.996 (0.022)
>13 0.996 (0.022)
>14 0.996 (0.022)
>15 0.996 (0.022)
```

Comment: Maybe you are overfitting? Can you use a test set (not seen during training) to evaluate the model?

Comment: Just tried using a test set within the dataset and got relatively similar results.

Comment: Please, fix indentation

Comment: Corrected. That was a result of me transferring code over from Jupyter NB. Indentation is correct on code.